# Vue Cant render data from axios inside datatable

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-reactivity

i am trying to get data from axios and then render it in datable component
how you can see the hardcoded data is renderd every time , but i cant implement data from axios call,
i am loading same format data from axios and then try to update my hardocded rows but nothing happens, i am not shure thath i am doing it right way
can somone help

```
<template>
<div>
  <mdb-datatable-2 v-model="data" />
  
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbDatatable2 } from 'mdbvue';
export default {
name: 'Datatable',
components: {
  mdbDatatable2
},
data() {
  return { 
   data: {
      columns: [
        {
          label: 'Account',
          field: 'account',
          sort: true
        },
        {
          label: 'bt_mac',
          field: 'bt_mac',
          sort: true
        },
        {
          label: 'rssi',
          field: 'rssi',
          sort: true
        },
        {
          label: 'time_stamp',
          field: 'time_stamp',
          sort: true
        }
      ],
      rows: [{
          account: 'Tiger Nixon',
          bt_mac: 'System Architect',
          rssi: 'Edinburgh',
          time_stamp: '2011/04/25',
          time: '2011/04/25'
        },
        {
          account: 'Garrett Winters',
          bt_mac: 'Accountant',
          rssi: 'Tokyo',
          time_stamp: '2018/04/25',
          time: '2011/04/25'
        },
        {
          account: 'Ashton Cox',
          bt_mac: 'unior Technical Author',
          rssi: 'San Francisco',
          time_stamp: '2009/01/12',
          time: '2011/04/25'
        },]
    
        
  
  }
   }
},
 methods: {
    getSnomData () {
     this.axios.get('http://172.27.11.174:1818/testJson').then((response) => {
     console.log(this.data);    
    console.log(response.data.rows);  this.rows = response.data;
 
    console.log(this.data);
    return response;
    })
        }
},

created() {

this.getSnomData();
 

} 
,
mounted () {
    this.getSnomData();
}


}
</script>
```

Comment: you should do `this.data.rows = response.data;` or `this.$set(this.data,'rows',response.data)`

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim i tryed it know what i can see it loads inside vue but dont update my table values , hier is some image of it  https://ibb.co/7gZmmNw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.data.rows = response.data.data;
that helped in my case